# acpi pcc probe failed

Tags: release-freya

Your system is very beautiful! 
But I stalknulsya a problem after installing the driver on the GTX970 system is not loaded (started only after recovering of one line).

[0.634731] acpi pcc probe failed.

Comment: I have the same issue with my system built with Asrock z87-M8, i5-4460s, and GTX 750 TI. Looking for an answer.